# Assertion error on python while running rowcol test

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing

I am running a test rowcol basically multiplying the row and column to get the out come to see if it is equal to the original. I did this on paper how matrices are done. But when I run it it always says the the assertion error is not equal. 
I've double checked everything to make sure no extra indention no extra numbers or anything.

code:

```
def test_rowcol_product_1( self ):
        """ Row col product """
        row = [4,5,6]
        col = [3,7,11]
        self.assertEqual( rowcol_product(row, col), 4*3 + 5*7 + 6*11 )
```

error I receive:

```
self.assertEqual( rowcol_product(row, col), 4*3 + 5*7 + 6*11 )
AssertionError: None != 113
```

Comment: Where and how is `rowcol_ product` defined? Also are you sure it returns anything? (According to the error it doesn't)

Comment: To expand @UnholySheep 's comment: The `rowcol_product` function returns `None` and that is the issue here, because that is not equal to the expected value (113). So either `rowcol_product` has a problem in it or works different than you expect. So it would be helpful to know what that actually is.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  You haven't posted all of the applicable code, and you haven't traced the return value of **rowcol_product**.

Comment: Congratulations, your test found a bug! `rowcol_product` isn't returning its calculation. Since the bug is in `rowcol_product` and you don't show us that code, there is nothing we can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a pre-emptive guess here: **rowcol_product** doesn't return a value at all.  For instance (using a very simple implementation):

For instance:

```
def rowcol_product(a, b):
    prod = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        prod += a[i]*b[i]

Without a statement at the end to explicitly return the computed total,

    return prod

... the default return from the function is **None**.  Add the missing statement to the bottom of the function.
```

Comment: I don't think we can answer this question until OP posts his code. Who knows what evil lurks inside.

Comment: I'm quite aware of the possible evils.  This is pre-emptive strike.  I took a cue from the expected value in the **assert**, and tried to save everyone some time.  On the other hand, the first vote to close is mine.